# Fusion table, map and displaying images?

Tags: google-maps, html, google-fusion-tables

I´ve set up a Google Maps displaying points from af fusion table. Is it possible to display the images related to the points, like when mouseover? (html hover?)

Comment: Hi, have you ever find an answer for this question? I'm wondering the same. I need to create a map with pictures displaying. Like ESRIs' Story Maps. Please comment, thanks.

Comment: Hi Delonix. Yep, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine the scale of the pics as you want. Look here how to do that:
https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2592809?hl=en

And here´s my own map with Fusion tables:

[Documentation, waterstreams](https://fusiontables.googleusercontent.com/fusiontables/embedviz?q=select%20col7%20from%201CehNwZSeeE0eqhVWu0-CaKOynYiT0YuWyjz0KGMe&viz=MAP&h=false&lat=55.76520461660028&lng=12.23258969732421&t=1&z=12&l=col7&y=2&tmplt=3&hml=KML)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another Google Fusion Tables map that displays images (and other attributes) *on click*:

http://geohipster.com/map-geohipster-sightings/

The original poster asked about displaying images on mouseover (html hover). I don't know whether Google Fusion Tables supports that.